# llamar a una api como si fuera el cliente desde getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js

Tengo una aplicación de next alojada en amplify, el backend esta en un ec2, con cloudflare le añadí los headers de localización ip a los 2, pero solo aparece en el backend, en next aparece CloudFront-Viewer-Country que se lo añade amplify por defecto
en una pagina de next tengo getServerSideProps donde llamo al backend pero entonces cuando consulto la pagina cuando esta en producción, mostrara la localización del servidor.

¿como puedo hacer que se consulte como si fuera el cliente?

en producción puedo obtener la dirección ip correcta de los headers de getServerSideProps y usar una api de localización por ip pero quiero evitar apis externas por ahora

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => async ({  query, req }) => {
    const { data } = await axios.post("pagina.com/static-routes/maininventories/show-headers");

data.data["cf-ipcountry"] //"US"
....

}
```

en backend con express, se creo la ruta para probar cloudflare o cloudfront para añadir los headers

```
public async showHeaders(req: Request, res: Response) {
        res.send(req.headers)
    }
```